# GDB crashes with: ImportError: No module named libstdcxx.v6.printers

Tags: python, gcc, debugging, gdb

I have a problem with GDB. Whenever I try to debug any C++ program, just after running it, GDB gives this error:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/errikos/Workspaces/tests/a.out 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py", line 59, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named libstdcxx.v6.printers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py", line 59, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named libstdcxx.v6.printers
```

After that, GDB continues running (ie. does not crash completely).

I am aware that there are several bug reports about this ([here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/921839), [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.6/+bug/908163) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/952999)). In the second report, there is also a claim that there is a fix released. In the third one, there is a symlink workaround, that did not work for me (and which I do not like, even if it worked).

Has anyone found a workaround for this? Any missing package?

**Note:** I have the Ubuntu Toolchain test builds (ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test) PPA activated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/$triple/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py`; if it were operating correctly, you would only see the `ImportError` once, and the pretty-printers would work.

See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=701935#18 for some information about what's going wrong here.  This worked okay in Debian's `gcc-4.7`, but until recently did not work in `gcc-4.8` on Debian.  I'm not sure if I even *tried* this with `gcc-4.6`.

Regardless, you *can* patch that file to look in the right place.

Comment: Could you provide a sample patch?

Comment: This has been probably fixed by the latest packages in ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test, as I do not get this error anymore. I had lost interest in this as I have not been doing much C/C++ development lately. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Note: Matthias Klose has since moved the relevant file to a place where it doesn't trigger the spurious `ImportError` anymore in Debian unstable.

Comment: How can I patch this?

Comment: @becko: What is your exact installed version of libstdc++6?

Comment: libstdc++6 version 4.8.2-19. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits.

Comment: @becko: Hmm, what value for `_dir` does your libstdc++*-gdb.py file compute?

Comment: @SamB I have no idea what you're talking about. Can you explain?

Comment: @becko: Perhaps we should take this to chat or something? (I'm not sure how, exactly, to do that though.)

Comment: @SamB Sorry, I can't use chat. Proxy issues.

Comment: @becko have you managed to solve it? If so, how?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga Not sure. Now I am using Xubuntu 15.04 and it doesn't seem to be happening anymore.